# How to fix the heading in html table using css

Tags: css, html, dom

I am creating an HTML file I am creating a table in it . I want that header of the table should be fixed and scrolling should work for the rest of the table not for the headings.
 I am using the following code for this. Suggest me the  best alternative for this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.underDiv{
overflow:hidden;
width:50px;
height:150px;
background-color:#FF00FF;
position:relative;
z-index:1;
}

.overflowDiv{
z-index:4;
position:absolute;
left:25px;
top:25px;
height:50px;
width:50px;
background-color:#00FF00;
}
</style>

</head>

 <body>
  <table>
  <div>
    <div class="underDiv">
     <th>Roll no</th>
     <th> Name</th>
     </div>
    <div class="overflowDiv">
    <tr>
    <td>4085</td>
    <td>john</td>
    </tr>
    </div>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are handy jQuery solutions for this, check out Waypoints > Sticky:

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/